# Compositor Warning: Your display driver does not support OpenGL, GLSL shaders

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, gentoo, opengl, enlightenment

Using Enlightenment on Gentoo in Virtualbox and at startup I'm getting

`Compositor Warning: Your display driver does not support OpenGL, GLSL shaders or no OpenGL engines were compiled or installed for Evas or Ecore-Evas. Falling back to software engine. You will need an OpenGl 2.0 (or OpenGL ES 2.0) capable GPU to use OpenGL with compositing.`

With `glxinfo | grep 'OpenGL'` I'm getting

```
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa/X.org
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.1.0, 128 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.3.4
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 20.3.4
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 20.3.4
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

So clearly I have it (or the drivers or whatever) installed. Is it just not detecting it?

Comment: 2 Questions: 1. Is Gentoo the Host OS or the Guest OS? 2. Are you trying to use Video Passthrough?  See [Chapter 35 of the README](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/450.80.02/README/kms.html) if Host and [Gentoo Wiki: Virtualbox](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/VirtualBox#GPU_acceleration) for configuration help.

Comment: @eyoung100 Gentoo is the guest OS. I use an Intel GPU so that first link doesn't matter. I've already looked at and followed the second one with no results.

Comment: Apologies for missing your comment.  If you still need help please post the output of `lspci` or `lahw`

Comment: @eyoung100 I've given up at this point. Enlightenment is pretty crap anyways.

Comment: I have a hunch... humor me. What does `lspci` show on the host? And on the guest?